# Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm trying to get the number of entries my DB holds - in the most simple way possible.

I'm trying to use the rawQuery "`SELECT Count(*) FROM Students`" and then from the cursor to do an getInt method to get the number and use it later on.

this is my method

```
public int getNumberOfEntries() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = ShaqedDB.NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES;
        Cursor d = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        d.moveToFirst();
        while (!d.isAfterLast()) {
           int numberReturned = d.getInt(0);
           d.moveToNext();
           return numberReturned;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I've looked everywhere - and I cannot find a solution to why am I keep getting the cursor error that the cursor cannot read row 0, col 1... even though I think I point it to col 0

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to write, you should use `getReadableDatabase();` instead of `getWritableDatabase();`.  In

```
d.getInt(0);
```

`0` is the index of column you want to retrieve the value. Don't hardcode the value. Ask the cursor to retrieve the column index

```
   d.getInt(d.getColumnIndexOrThrow("COLUMN_NAME"));
```

about your query, you want to now the number of results returned by your query. You can retrieve this value asking the cursor's count:

```
 public int getNumberOfEntries() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = ShaqedDB.NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES;
        Cursor d = db.rawQuery(query, null);   
        return d.getCount();
}
```

Comment: Hey man,I tried changing to ReadableDatabase() and the getColumn but I keep getting the same error... - just to clarify - all I want to know is how many entries (rows) does my table have, and return an 'int' value for it

Comment: try with `SELECT * FROM Students`

Comment: thanks Blackbelt, I changed my way approaching this and it worked